# Программное добавление файлов. Android

Tags: android, файлы, sqlite

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: программа хранит файлы, в которых содержатся различные статьи. Так как изначально файлы создавались только вручную, то создавал обычный текстовый документ и добавлял его в папку `Assets`. Однако потом возникла необходимость создания статей через само приложение. А так как эти файлы уже не только для чтения, то в `Assets` я их добавить не могу. Планировал использовать базу данных SQLite для этого, чтобы хранить там пути к файлам, но кажется неудобным, если часть файлов хранится в одном месте (`Assets`), а часть в другом (где-то на устройстве). Как вариант был все хранить на устройстве, но тогда непонятно, как файлы из `Assets` перекинуть куда-то на устройство. Есть ли какие-то более оптимальные варианты?

Comment: Заголовок не отражает сути вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Храни в таблице SQLite; Напиши процедуру которая читает из Assets и добавляет в базу (можно построчно); во-второй таблице храни оглавление (список статей) там же можно указать где хранится статья Assets/бд

Comment: то есть по сути продублировать данные,т.к они одновременно будут и в Assets и БД, или я неправильно понял?

Comment: После загрузки в бд из Assets можно будет удалить. Пока тестируешь - дублирование пригодится